# How to get all the table data row wise to .ts file Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have been using primeng for datatables and I am working with some attendance for Students and **when I click Submit I should get all the data to my .ts file to check who are present and absent.**

My Output:
[image]

My Code:

```
<div class="primetable" style="box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgba(69,90,100,.08);">
      <p-table [value]="student"
          [columns]="cols"
          #dt
          class="primetable"
          [paginator]="true"
          [rows]="10" [style]="{width:'100%'}"
          [autoLayout]="true"
          [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,15,20,25]">

          <ng-template pTemplate="header"
              let-columns>
              <tr>
                  <th style="padding: 15px 15px;color: #1e6bb8;background: white"
                      *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col.header}}</th>
              </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="body"
              let-student
              let-i="rowIndex"
              >
              <tr [pSelectableRow]="student">
                  <td >{{i+1}}</td>
                  <td>{{student.regnum}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <p-checkbox name="groupname" value="val1" [(ngModel)]="student.attendance" (click)="attendance($event, student)"></p-checkbox>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="footer" let-student>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" style="width: 50%;"
          class="btn btn-2 btn-2g">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
      </p-table>
  </div>
```

**Here I triggered event for just click on Checkbox so I am getting data only for Checked Students but I need whole table data as json data in .ts file**

Help me friends, Happy Coding
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="primetable" style="box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgba(69,90,100,.08);">
  <p-table [value]="student"
      [columns]="cols"
      #dt
      class="primetable"
      [paginator]="true"
      [rows]="10" [style]="{width:'100%'}"
      [autoLayout]="true"
      [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,15,20,25]">

      <ng-template pTemplate="header"
          let-columns>
          <tr>
              <th style="padding: 15px 15px;color: #1e6bb8;background: white"
                  *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col.header}}</th>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body"
          let-student
          let-i="rowIndex"
          >
          <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowstudent">
              <td >{{i+1}}</td>
              <td>{{rowstudent.regnum}}</td>
              <td>
                <p-checkbox name="groupname" value="val1" [(ngModel)]="rowstudent.attendance" (click)="attendance($event, student)"></p-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="footer" let-student>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" style="width: 50%;"
      class="btn btn-2 btn-2g">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

Comment: Can u give some explanation of what u pasted here

Comment: [pSelectableRow]="rowstudent" not be same instance as student .then it will give single row information

Comment: you had set [pSelectableRow]="student"

Comment: you can user directly this.student in                                                                      public attendance($event) {
// your other code logic

console.log(this.student)
}